# git 8728 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initial

Tags: git, cygwin

I am trying to solve the following issue:

```
$ git pull
      2 [main] git 8728 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initial
ization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
error: cannot fork() for rev-list: Resource temporarily unavailable
error: could not run rev-list
remote: Counting objects: 43, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
remote: Total 31 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0)
1301582 [main] git 8728 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initial
ization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
error: cannot fork() for unpack-objects: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: fetch-pack: unable to fork off unpack-objects
```

According to some google search I need somehow to run rebaseall from my cygwin shell. Here is what I did:

From sytem32/cmd.exe ("Run" menu and entering "cmd") I execute:

```
cd \cygwin\bin
dash
PATH=. rebaseall -v
```

I get:

```
$ ./rebaseall -v
rebaseall: only ash or dash processes are allowed during rebasing
    Exit all Cygwin processes and stop all Cygwin services.
    Execute ash (or dash) from Start/Run... or a cmd or command window.
    Execute '/bin/rebaseall' from ash (or dash).
```

ok, trying again using: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe:

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>cd c:\

c:\>cd cygwin

c:\cygwin>cd bin

c:\cygwin\bin>ash
$ ./rebaseall -v
rebaseall: only ash or dash processes are allowed during rebasing
    Exit all Cygwin processes and stop all Cygwin services.
    Execute ash (or dash) from Start/Run... or a cmd or command window.
    Execute '/bin/rebaseall' from ash (or dash).
```

How am I supposed either:

1. Solve my initial issue
2. Run this "rebaseall" thingy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have similar issue on Windows 7 (32-bit). It looks like

```
$ git pull
C:\PROGRA~1\Git\bin\sh.exe: *** 1. unable to allocate heap 0x10050000, heap_chunk_size 268435456, pid 4080, Win32 error 0
      0 [main] sh 3964 sync_with_child: child 4080(0x174) died before initialization with status code 0x1
   1064 [main] sh 3964 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Unfortunately rebasing didn't help in my case (I followed the approach proposed in the article "[No more STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION on Cygwin under Windows7](http://x-aeon.com/wp/2011/08/05/no-more-status_access_violation-on-cygwin-under-windows7/)")

According to the <del>[issue 122](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=122)</del> [issue 122](http://web.archive.org/web/20130523160129/http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=122) the problem is definitely with msys-1.0.dll...

Comment: I am having the same problem in Windows 7 (32-bit). Did you get any solution for it @AntonK ? I simply installed the Git-1.9.5 for windows platform.

Comment: @med, I don't work with Git any longer, and I can't remember whether and how I had solved the problem. According to the discussion on the issue 122 (it is available in web.archive.org) the problem might have caused by an error in msysgit. I would expect it was solved already.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the git problem but your rebaseall command should work.  You most likely have some Cygwin process still running.

- Is your X server shut down?  Close it from the taskbar (X icon)--if you don't see it there it may have crashed but remained as a stale process.  In that case, kill it from task manager (look for XWin.exe).
- Also, if you have background services running, you'll need to stop those--see http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.setup.html#faq.setup.uninstall-service on how to list and stop those